# Class nested inside a trait: what is the value?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have been working with some Play Framework apps that commonly define classes nested in traits. Here is a contrived, simple example.

## services/UsefulServiceComponent.scala

```
trait UsefulServiceComponent {

  val usefulService: UsefulService

  class UsefulService {
    def doSomething(thing: Thing): OtherThing = {
      // etc.
    }
  }
}
```

## controllers/TheController.scala

```
import services.UsefulServiceComponent

object TheController extends Controller with UsefulServiceComponent {

  val usefulService = new UsefulService

  def findOtherThing(id: Long) = {
    val thing = ??? // Get it from somewhere
    usefulService.doSomething(thing)
  }

  // etc.
}
```

Is this pattern common? What value is gained by nesting `UsefulService` inside `UsefulServiceComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

Scoping. Also you can decorate/facade/adapt the service

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain further or link to a reference on scoping or decoration etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is called the "cake pattern" and is a way to do dependency injection in Scala. I don't want to duplicate the existing explanations, and they are too large for a quick answer in any case, so here are some links: http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/, http://www.warski.org/blog/2010/12/di-in-scala-cake-pattern/, http://www.warski.org/blog/2014/02/using-scala-traits-as-modules-or-the-thin-cake-pattern/ (Searching Google or SO for the name will give you more.)